# One-off Read-only SQL Statement Verification in MySQL 5.5?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an interface that I want to allow an arbitrary SQL select statement (as an input string) to be input that will select data from a given table for use in an operation.  I want to make sure that this statement does not make changes to the database.

```
string query = GetStringFromForm(...);

DatabaseStatement statement(query);

statement.execute();

while (statement.fetch(...))
    ...
```

One way to implement this would be to create a new database user with the appropriate permissions and then execute the statement under that user.  This would be a hassle as it would require setting up this new user and creating a new database connection for it and so on.

Is there a way to isolate the permissions for a single statement MySQL 5.5?  Or some other way to do this?

Comment: Hassle? It probably takes less time than posting a question here ;-)

Comment: The hassle is mainly the new database connection, it currently uses a global connection pool (one per thread) which is transparent to the upper layer, so it would require bypassing this.  What would be nicer is a command that could temporarily limit the permissions of the current database connection somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With MySQL 5.6 you can do:

```
START TRANSACTION READ ONLY;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/commit.html

I think it's what you're looking for, but you have to upgrade to 5.6 to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't connect to the database with the same login for ***everything***.

At the very least you *should* use thee logins for this achitecture:

1. A development level login for creating tables, etc
2. The login used by your application to make the application run
3. The login used to execute user specified queries

This means that your application login only has the permissions it needs - to read or write to the tables necessary, not to do everything to every table; application logins shouldn't need to be able to CREATE or DROP tables, for example.

This limits the impact of mistakes in code, but also the scope to which someone could hack your system *(such as with SQL Injection attacks)*.

It also means that the login for running user specific queries needs only to be granted SELECT permissions, and only to the tables/views/function that it should be able to use.  If they try to run an INSERT or a DELETE that they don't have permissions for, you can catch the error and tell the user that they're a `very naughty boy` - secure in the mind the the RDBMS simply won't let the user damage anything that you haven't already given them permission to do.

In short, RDBMS already have login permission architectures.  Use those to limit the permissions and functionallity of different aspects of your code.

I would not try to re-invent this wheel.  It is *extremely* likely that there is a trick or hack that you missed that exposes a vulnerability in your application.  I appreciate that you say this is a hassle, but it really is the right way of doing things, and the only reliable way of doing things.  There's a reason that it's the standard approach to data security, sorry.

*(And trust me, even if no-one is trying to hack your system, eventually someone will type some screwball query in - **accidentally** bypassing your security and making a pigs ear of your database.)*

Comment: The only way to get data into a database statement in our architecture currently is through a placeholder `(?)` in a prepared query (which are all string literals), so as far as I know this makes us immune to injection attacks correct?  Placeholders can't take arbitrary SQL right?  So the only way a bad statement can be executed is if a programmer types it into their code, which they can just as easily do at their development level login.

Comment: What is I supply this string?  `SELECT 1 AS dummy); DELETE FROM aTable;`  The `);` is going to really screw with your query.  This is *exactly* the type of situation that is open to SQL Injection Attacks.

Comment: This won't interpolate in a prepared query with placeholders.  The string will be effectively "escaped" as a quoted string.

Comment: Any string that can contain SQL that you intend to Execute can be abused.  If you supply it as a string parameter, it can't be executed.  If it is supplied as a replacement part for dynamic SQL, it can be abused.  Without a full SQL parser and permissions control mechanism, it can be abused.  If you don't believe this, create a site and ask SO users to attack it...

Comment: Yes, of course.  That is why our architecture doesn't allow "dynamic SQL" because it is susceptible to an SQL injection attack.  All SQL queries are string literals with placeholders, which are not susceptible to SQL injection attacks.